# Matlab does not respond after mlreportgen.dom.*

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to put an image into a word document. After I run this script below, I get a word document with a pic inside. Everything is fine till this moment. The problem starts when I am running the script once again. Matlab can not finish the script and I have to restart Matlab each time, which is very annoying. It seems there is some conflict. I tried to delete pic and word document after the first run and before a second run but that does not help.

```
import mlreportgen.dom.*
d = Document('imageArea','docx');


x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;  %Plot
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);


saveas(gcf,'myPlot_img.png'); % Save figure in folder


plot1 = Image('myPlot_img.png'); % Append plot to word file
plot1.Style={ScaleToFit}; 
append(d,plot1);

close(d); % Close
rptview(d.OutputPath);
```

Please Help. Thank You

Comment: Try to use the MATLAB debugger or pause your program to identify where your program gets stuck.

Comment: I can see that Matlab is busy with the script and this state never ends. No, I do not see any error.